# Allow space in target of GCC makefile

Tags: gcc, makefile, mingw, target, space

Is there a way to get spaces inside target names working when using make.exe? It seems to be impossible if this really ancient bug report is correct:
http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?712

For reference, the big problem is that pieces of makefile commands like:

```
"foo bar baz": $(OBJ)
    $(CPP) $(LINKOBJ) -o $(BIN) $(LIBS)
```

... seem to get treated as three separate commands: one to build "foo (note the included "), one to build bar, and lastly, one to build baz" (again, including "). This is because make.exe seems to be using space as a delimiter.

However, it's reasonable to assume that one might want to build "Hello World.exe" for example. This doesn't seem to be possible. Double quotes don't work, and neither does escaping the separate words (I've read that somewhere, don't remember the link):

```
"foo\\ bar\\ baz": $(OBJ)
    $(CPP) $(LINKOBJ) -o $(BIN) $(LIBS)
```

Is there any other way to fix this? The official manual only confirms the tokenize-by-spaces stuff, but doesn't provide a way to use space for any other purpose:
http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Rule-Syntax

**Edit:** as suggested, I've tried single slashes too, but these have the exact same effect as double slashes. Make complains it can't find rules for the first word:

```
mingw32-make.exe: *** No rule to make target `foo', needed by `all'.  Stop.
```

The executable "foo bar baz.exe" is correctly produced though, but linking is done each time per word.

Answer (score 4):

as Matthias said, it's a matter of "\ ", but of double quote too. Here is how I succeded into this :

```
EXECUTABLE=foo\ bar\ baz
all: $(SOURCES) $(EXECUTABLE)
$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS)
                $(CC) $(OBJECTS) -o "$@" $(LDFLAGS)
```

Note the double quotes around the $@
It seems to me that when make reach the target "$(EXECUTABLE)" it expands the "\ ", so the command line becomes

```
gcc file.o -o foo bar baz -LFlags
```

which is not what you want, you want double quotes around the name of the file.

Now you are on windows and I don't remember how it deals with spaces in names, so as Matthias said, first check how "cmd.exe" deals with spaces (except by surrounding name with double quotes...)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of double backslash use single ones. The following Makefile works (at least for gnu make):

```
goal:   foo\ bar

foo\ bar:
    gcc -o "foo bar" "foo bar.c"
```

Comment: @Orwell: Then, it seems to be a matter of operating system. How do you specify a file with spaces in name at your shell?

Comment: Colons in target names also need to be quoted: `some\:target\ name: ...` - maybe other characters also.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe easier to consider a simpler Makefile, which ignores the dependencies in the standard `targetRule: dependencies` invocation. The OP is for Windows, and the below is done on Linux in the `bash` shell; but it should probably be applicable to Windows using the `bash` shell via `cygwin`, I guess. I have the following in my `Makefile` (note, there should be a <kbd>TAB</kbd> before the `echo` commands, which SO converts to spaces):

```
testA:
    echo "testA"

unrelated:
    echo "unrelated"

testA\ clean:
    echo "testA clean"

clean:
    echo "clean"
```

If I call `make` with targets `clean` or `testA` in the `bash` shell terminal, I get the expected results:

```
$ make testA 
echo "testA"
testA
$ make clean
echo "clean"
clean
```

Now, if I call `make testA clean` just written as is, the `bash` shell will split the arguments at spaces, so `make` will receive two arguments, and will run them separately:

```
$ make testA clean
echo "testA"
testA
echo "clean"
clean
```

... but if I wrap the target supplied to `make` in quotes - or if I escape the space - the shell will understand that it is supposed to be a single argument with a space inside, and will propagate it as such to `make`, which will proceed to execute what is written as the `testA\ clean` target rule:

```
$ make "testA clean"
echo "testA clean"
testA clean
$ make testA\ clean
echo "testA clean"
testA clean
```

One consequence of this, is that unfortunately you cannot "TAB" at the command line for autocompletion of `testA\ clean`; if you type `make te`<kbd>TAB</kbd> at the command line, only `testA` will be autocompleted automatically (and the `testA\ clean` will not be shown as an autocomplete option).